# Custom Checkout Field for Woocommerce with dynamic options

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dynamic, checkout

I want to have dynamic options for my checkout dropdown field. The options must be users of specific roles that are in WordPress users. How can I achieve it? Below is the code that I am working with. In the first function, we can get all administrator users. I want users to be in options of the dropdown in the select field of checkout.

```
**User Roles**

function get_users_by_role($role, $orderby, $order) {
    $args = array(
        'role'    => 'administrator',
        'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
        );
   $users = get_users( $args );
   return $users;
}

**Dropdown Field**

function everest_custom_dropdown_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['everestmerchant_extra_dropdown_fields']['dropdown'] = array(
           'label'         => __('Leader Name', 'woocommerce'),
           'placeholder'   => _x('Leader Name', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
           'required'      => true,
           'class'         => array( 'wps-drop' ),
           'clear'         => true,
           'type'          => 'select',
           'options'       => array(
                                   'option 1' => __('option 1', 'woocommerce' ),
                                   'option 2' => __('option 2', 'woocommerce'                                                                      
                                   )//end of options
      );
     return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'everest_custom_dropdown_fields' );
```

Comment: Just replace `'options' => array(..` with `'options' => $users` where `$users`  
is an array with the result of the `get_users_by_role()` function

Answer (score 0):

> Get All Leaders

```
function get_leaders($role) {
 $args = array(
    'role'    => $role,
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
 );
 $leaders = ['' => 'Please Select'];
 $users = get_users( $args );
 if($users){
    foreach($users as $user){
        $leaders[$user->data->ID] = $user->data->display_name;
    }
 }
 return $leaders;
}
```

> Add Leader field in checkout page

```
function leader_name_select_field( $checkout ){

woocommerce_form_field( 'leader_name', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
    'label' => 'Leader Name',
    'options' => get_leaders('administrator')
), $checkout->get_value( 'leader_name' ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'leader_name_select_field' );
```

> Save Selected field in database.

```
function save_leader_name_of_order( $order_id ){
if( !empty( $_POST['leader_name'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'leader_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['leader_name'] ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_leader_name_of_order' );
```

> Show saved field in order page in dashboard

```
function leader_name_show_on_order_detail_page($order){
$leader_id = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'leader_name', true );
$leader = get_user_by( 'ID', $leader_id );
if($leader_id && $leader){
    echo '<p class="form-field form-field-wide">';
    echo '<label>Leader Name</label>';
    echo '<p> ' . $leader->data->display_name . '</p>';
    echo '</p>';
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'leader_name_show_on_order_detail_page', 10, 1 );
```